# bootstrap icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

estou tentando por um icon bootstrap, mas não estou conseguindo..

```
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/xd.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cardslider.css">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row  " id="lul">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">x</span>
              <h3 class="mr-auto mt-3">Novidades</h3>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary prev mt-3 mb-3" href="" title="go back"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary next mt-3 mb-3" href="" title="more"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
```

importei no css

```
@import url(http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css);
```

e fica assim .[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara não importe o CSS do BS3 dentro do 4 vai dar problema d+! Vou tentar ver o que está pegando e tento te ajudar. o BS3 usavo o FW4, já BS4 não usa mais na biblioteca geral, mas indica que uso com ele o FW5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara basicamente vc está usando as classes dos Glyphicon que era a biblioteca de ícons padrão do Bootstrap 3, dentro do Bootstrap 4, porém indexando o CSS do Fontawesome 5 e fazendo um @inport do Fontawesom 4 rss... está meio que tudo errado... Escolha apenas um deles para trabalhar...

Eu te indico continuar com o Fontawesome 5 mesmo, mas para isso vc precisa usar as classes corretas. Aqui tem um link com todos os ícones deles https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet e aqui um basicão de como usar as classes: https://fontawesome.com/icons/address-book?style=solid

Basicamente para usar qualquer ícone vc tem que incluir uma tag assim: `<i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>`

Veja como fica no seu código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    

    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-adjust">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-address-card"></i>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row  " id="lul">
            <div class="col-12 d-flex">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">x</span>
              
              <h3 class="mr-auto mt-3">Novidades</h3>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary prev mt-3 mb-3" href="" title="go back"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary next mt-3 mb-3" href="" title="more"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

olá

Esta importação que você realizou está realizando refere-se à biblioteca dos " font-awesome icons". '

tente inserir tambem esses links:

'` https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: eu já inserir tudo isso man

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: editei e coloquei todos os import's que fiz.

Comment: Bom, pelo que você passou aqui, o script do bootstrap está vindo do cdn, enquanto o css você está buscando de uma pasta local. Tente colocar as importações ou direto pelos links do cdn ou apenas pelas suas pastas locais. Caso não funcione com as pastas locais verifique se as versões do seu bootstrap estão iguais. Recomendo tambem dar uma olhada neste link https://www.w3schools.com/booTsTrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_default&stacked=h onde é possível ver como realizar a importação

Comment: eu importando o <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> funciona porém bagunça todo o resto do meu codigo :(

Comment: Pode ser conflito de versão do bootstrap que vc tem na máquina local com o do servidor. Verifique se vc possui o bootstrap.min.js baixado localmente com o css e tente retirar as importações via link. Caso tudo dê errado, verifique se o caminho da importação dos seus arquivos estão seguindo o caminho correto

Comment: Caso minha solução tenha resolvido seu problema, por favor marque-a como resposta! :)